# Linux `watch` segmentation fault

Tags: watch

When I try to use Linux `watch` with a command which returns color output, I get the error: `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

The command itself is the following:

```
watch --color --no-title --interval 1 ls\ --color
```

If I remove either `--no-title` or `--color` (from `watch` or `ls`), the error doesn't show up.

What can be the reason of the error?

Arch; watch from procps-ng 3.3.11; zsh 5.1.1; GNU bash 4.3.4.2

Comment: I suspect you might have a faulty memory chip.

Comment: I filed an [issue](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/13).

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm.... Which `watch` package do you have?....

```
# watch -v
watch from procps-ng 3.3.9

# watch --help

    Usage:
     watch [options] command

        Options:
        [..]
          -c, --color            interpret ANSI color sequences
        [..]
          -t, --no-title         turn off header
        [..]
```

Comment: watch from procps-ng 3.3.11

Answer (score 0):

Removing and installing solved the problem for me:

```shell
sudo apt-get remove watch
sudo apt-get install watch
```

**Note:** the standard output of these operations give a false sense of "nothing has changed", but does actually fixes the issue.